# How to dynamically emphasis a specific category on a bar chart with a background on echarts-for-react

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I'm using echarts and i'm trying to emphasis the "current picked bar" by adding background color.
I want to be able to click on one of the bars, and by doing so the month will change and the background color will be applied on the back of that month.

Makes sense?
Here's a codesandbox that emphasis my idea:
https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-cloud-zy44j?file=/src/App.js

But going over and documentation it seems as though there is no option to add backgroundColor to just one category / bar. I tried using another series but that did not work.

I'm also attaching pictures to explain what should be.

And also attaching the code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import ReactEcharts from "echarts-for-react";
import moment from "moment";

export default function App() {
  const [month, setMonth] = useState(0);
  const onChartClick = (params) => {
    const monthClicked = moment().month(params.name).month();
    setMonth(monthClicked);
  };
  console.log(month);
  const renderChart = () => {
    const _onEvents = {
      click: onChartClick
    };
    const option = {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      tooltip: {
        trigger: "item"
      },
      grid: {
        left: "0px",
        right: "0px",
        bottom: "0px",
        top: "0px",
        containLabel: false,
        show: false
      },
      xAxis: {
        position: "top",
        axisLine: {
          show: false
        },
        axisTick: {
          show: false
        },
        axisLabel: {
          inside: true,
          color: "#74818f",
          fontFamily: "SegoePro-Regular",
          fontSize: 12
        },
        splitNumber: 1,
        splitLine: {
          show: true,
          lineStyle: {
            color: [
              "#ffffff",
              "#eaeaea",
              "#eaeaea",
              "#eaeaea",
              "#eaeaea",
              "#eaeaea",
              "#eaeaea",
              "#eaeaea",
              "#eaeaea",
              "#eaeaea",
              "#eaeaea",
              "#eaeaea",
              "#ffffff",
              "#ffffff",
              "#ffffff"
            ]
          }
        },
        type: "category",
        data: [
          "January",
          "February",
          "March",
          "April",
          "May",
          "June",
          "July",
          "August",
          "September",
          "October",
          "November",
          "December"
        ]
      },
      yAxis: {
        scale: true,
        type: "value",
        axisLabel: {
          show: false
        },
        axisTick: {
          show: false
        },
        axisLine: {
          show: false,
          onZero: false
        },
        splitLine: {
          show: false
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "Monthly Income",
          type: "bar",
          barWidth: "30%",
          barGap: "-20%",
          label: {
            show: true,
            position: "top",
            fontSize: 12,
            fontFamily: "SegoePro-Bold",
            color: "#3d70ff"
          },
          itemStyle: {
            opacity: 0.7,
            color: "#3d70ff"
          },
          emphasis: {
            itemStyle: {
              opacity: 1
            }
          },
          tooltip: {},
          data: [
            8700,
            8700,
            10400,
            8699,
            8699,
            8699,
            8699,
            8699,
            11643.46,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          markArea: {
            silent: true,
            data: [
              [
                {
                  coord: [0, 0]
                },
                {
                  coord: [100, 100]
                }
              ]
            ],
            itemStyle: {
              color: "#f5f7fa"
            },
            label: {
              show: false
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    };
    const chartStyle = 280;
    return (
      <div id="chart_div">
        <div className="chart-wrapper">
          <ReactEcharts
            onEvents={_onEvents}
            option={option}
            style={{ height: chartStyle }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
  return renderChart();
}
```

[image: Current situation]
[image: Desired situation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the requirement is **unachievable** with this library. you can make x-axis clickable by  [`triggerEvent`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.triggerEvent) and do something with it; but adding a background or any other style on a "clicked" bar ( or axis ) needs a dedicated state; `clicked` state; which this library doesn't have; it listens to click events, but doesn't keep it on individual elements; so you can't style it based on a state that doesn't exist;
I was thinking about a workaround to make it happen by some applying css styles on clicked/hovered bars to fake the effect somehow but all the content are rendered inside a canvas, so no option remains; either use another library or write a chart drawer component yourself or forget this specific styling based on click;

Comment: Noooooo... I was afraid to get that answer. It makes me both happy and sad at the same time.
Do you think trying to create another series where all values are null except for the "clicked" bar, and add background to that series?
Because from what I've read it is also unachievable since all series's will get the background...

Comment: @nirshabi hmmm, rendering a new one with new state seems possible but I think there are some edge cases on the new rendered canvas which may cause you more problems than solving your issue, like clicking and another bar after, removing previous bar state.. this means that you are going hold that `clicked` state outside of the library, and kinda handle it yourself; why not trying another library by the way?

Comment: Maybe that's the better solution.. Do you have a better library to suggest?

Comment: @nirshabi I'd used `amcharts` in an admin panel and it was working very well; also I looked up for some libraries and this one looks like a good fit for your need: [`apexchart`](https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/column-charts/column-with-data-labels/)